# How to find the MySQL database table data directory when it's different from the global one

Tags: mysql, mysql5.6

When creating a new table, I specified the data directory with:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) 
TABLESPACE = innodb_file_per_table 
DATA DIRECTORY = '/alternative/directory';
```

How can I find the data directory of this table later?
If I do `select @@DataDirectory` I see the global data directory, not the custom data directory for this table in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a `t2.isl` file in the database directory beneath the MySQL DATADIR directory.
The .isl file is treated by MySQL like a symbolic link.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html for more details.